# List comprehension where the condition depends on the list being generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am new to Python programming. I want to rewrite the following code as a list comprehension:

```py
lx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
ly = [2, 5, 4]

lz = []
for x in lx:
    if x in ly and x not in lz:
        lz.append(x)
```

This will create a new list with common elements of `lx` and `ly`; but the condition `x not in lz` depends on the list that is being built. How can this code be rewritten as a list comprehension?

Comment: You cannot use list comprehension here, because you're checking if the current value of `x` was already added to the result list - with list comprehension the result list simply does not exist yet.

Comment: If I got it right, you don't want duplicates in `lz`. This will achieve the expected result: `lz = list(set(x for x in lx if x in ly))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it that way in a list comprehension as you cannot compare against the list `lz` that does not yet exist - assuming you are trying to avoid duplicates in the resulting list as in your example.

Instead, you can use the python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) which will enforce only a single instance of each value:

```py
lz = set(x for x in lx if x in ly)
```

And if what you are really after is a set intersection (elements in common):

```py
lz = set(lx) & set(ly)
```

---

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out by @Błotosmętek in the comments - using the set will not retain the order of the elements as the set is, by definition, unordered. If the order of the elements is significant a different strategy will be necessary.

Comment: When dealing with sets I guess it is better to use `and` instead of `&` (and the equivalent words for other set operations) just for code clarity sake.

Comment: @accdias No, those are definitely not equivalent. `&` is an overloaded operator which does set intersections; `and` is a logical operator which can never be overloaded.

Comment: If the order of the elements is important, ie. elements of `lz` should appear in the same order as they appeared in `lx`, this is not likely to work.

Comment: @kaya3, Are you sure? I've been using `and` and `or`, for intersection and union and they seem to work as expected. Can you show an example where the result is not right?

Comment: @accdias `{1} and {2}` is `{2}`. Likewise, `{1} or {2}` is `{1}`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek this is true. It depends on the persons requirements. I was just going off this in the question: `This will create a new list with common elements of lx and ly.`.

Comment: @kaya3, holly cow! I've been doing it wrong all this time! :facepalm: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer here is to use sets, because (1) sets naturally have distinct elements, and (2) sets are more efficient than lists for membership tests. So the simple solution is `list(set(lx) & set(ly))`.

However, sets do not preserve the order that elements are inserted in, so in case the order is important, here's a solution which preserves the order from `lx`. (If you want the order from `ly`, simply swap the roles of the two lists.)

```py
def ordered_intersection(lx, ly):
    ly_set = set(ly)
    return [ly_set.remove(x) or x for x in lx if x in ly_set]
```

Example:

```py
>>> ordered_intersection(lx, ly)
[2, 4, 5]
>>> ordered_intersection(ly, lx)
[2, 5, 4]
```

It works because `ly_set.remove(x)` always returns `None`, which is falsy, so `ly_set.remove(x) or x` always has the value of `x`.

The reason you cannot do this with a simpler list comprehension like `lz = [... if x in lz]` is because the whole list comprehension will be evaluated *before* the resulting list is assigned to the variable `lz`; so the `x in lz` test will give a `NameError` because there is no such variable yet.

---

That said, it **is** possible to rewrite your code to directly use a generator expression (which is somewhat like a list comprehension) instead of a `for` loop; but it is **bad code** and you shouldn't do this:

```py
def ordered_intersection_bad_dont_do_this(lx, ly):
    lz = []
    lz.extend(x for x in lx if x in ly and x not in lz)
    return lz
```

This is not just bad because of repeatedly testing membership of lists; it is worse, because it depends on an unspecified behaviour of the [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) method. In particular, it adds each element one by one rather than exhausting the iterator first and then adding them all at once. The docs don't say that this is guaranteed to happen, so this bad solution won't necessarily work in other versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use set, this can be another approach using list comprehension.

```
lx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
ly = [2, 5, 4]

lz=[]
[lz.append(x) for x in lx if (x in ly and x not in lz)]
print(lz)
```